# Number theory question to establish a relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we have $$p^2 + q^2 + r^2 +pq + qr + pr=3$$ so can we use only this relation to find $$\frac{p^2 +2q^2+r^2}{q^2}$$?

Comment: What are $p,q,r$? You used *number-theory* tag, so presumably integers, but pray tell :-)

Comment: Yes they are integers

Answer (score 3):

Written before we knew the variables were integers:  No.  What you know is symmetric in the variables, while what you want is not.  The only way you can evaluate it is if you can prove $ |p|=|q|=|r|$.  But by inspection, $p=\sqrt 3, q=0,r=0$ and $p=0,q=\sqrt 3, r=0$ both satisfy the original statement.  You can evaluate what you want in one case and not the other.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The equation can be rewritten as
$$
(p+q)^2+(p+r)^2+(q+r)^2=6.
$$

But I would still be skeptical, because the roles of $p,q,r$ are symmetric (as also pointed out by Ross). Rewriting does reduce it to a finite set of possibilities.

> Six can be written as a sum of three squares in relatively few ways. When you take into account sign variations, 24 ways, unless I made a mistake. Solve the resulting systems, and see what you get :-)